# Transform a json request to a JsArray[T] in a play application

Tags: json, scala, rest, playframework

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application using Scala.

In my controller I've define a class that represents a tag and an implicit reader like the following:

```
private case class RestTag(tag: String)
private implicit val tagReader = Json.reads[RestTag]//reader of RestTag objects
```

In my application I've a REST method that get a json request in the following format:

```
{"tags": [{"tag": "cat1:attri1:"}, 
          {"tag": "cat2:attr1"}
         ]
}
```

How can i parse the `request.body.asJson` and passed from the json to a `List[String]` containing all the `"tag"` value??
It's possible to do that??
Or i need to change the `RestTag` class for match the Rest request??

The implementation of my controller method is something like the following:

```
def userMatchingTag = CorsAction.async { request =>
    val jsonObject = request.body.asJson
    jsonObject match {
      case Some(x) => x match {
        //here if x is JsArray[RestTag] transform it in a List[String] and do some work
        //otherwise returns a Future{BadRequest}

      }
      case None => Future{BadRequest("Need json")}
    }
  }
```

How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your `implicit val tagReader`:

```
val str =
    """{"tags": [{"tag": "cat1:attri1:"}, 
                 {"tag": "cat2:attr1"}]}"""

val tagsReads = (JsPath \ "tags").read[List[RestTag]].map{_.map{_.tag}}

val res = Json.parse(str).validate(tagsReads)
// JsSuccess(List(cat1:attri1:, cat2:attr1),/tags)

res match {
    case JsSuccess(list, _) => println(list)
    case e: JsError => println(e)
}
//List(cat1:attri1:, cat2:attr1)
```

Without `RestTag` class:

```
val tagsReads =
  (JsPath \ "tags").read(Reads.list(
                           (JsPath \ "tag").read[String]
                         ))

val res = Json.parse(str).validate(tagsReads)
// JsSuccess(List(cat1:attri1:, cat2:attr1),/tags)
```

Comment: Thanks, why you have add the .map{_.map{_.tag}} statement on the tagsReads??

Comment: @albertoadami: without `map map` you'll get `JsResult[List[RestTag]]` instead of `JsResult[List[String]]`.